# Simple graph theory proofs using Coq

Tags: coq

Is there a well established Coq graph library for proving simple theorems ?

I would like to learn how to prove simple stuff like: "G1, G2 are isomorphic if and only if their complements are isomorphic".

Are there related/similar examples or tutorials available?

Comment: There's a [contribution about graph theory](http://coq.inria.fr/pylons/contribs/view/GraphBasics/v8.4) and a few other contributions also develop some graph theory. Why don't you implement graphs like you would in a functional programming language and then prove things about them? If you're new to Coq, I don't think you'll find tutorials that specific.

Comment: @autorewrite: I'm a newbie, but I would like to follow some examples that are related (e.g. some proofs about simple combinatorial objects: permutations, set operations, ecc.).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a demonstration.

Allow rewriting with equivalence relations.

```
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
```

A graph is a set of vertices along with an adjacency relation.

```
Definition graph : Type := {V : Type & V -> V -> bool}.
```

A graph from vertices and adjacency.

```
Definition create : forall V, (V -> V -> bool) -> graph := @existT _ _.
```

Vertices from a graph.

```
Definition vertices : graph -> Type := @projT1 _ _.
```

Adjacency from a graph.

```
Definition adjacent : forall g1, vertices g1 -> vertices g1 -> bool := @projT2 _ _.
```

The complement of a graph has the same vertices, but a negated adjacency relation.

```
Definition complement : graph -> graph := fun g1 => create (vertices g1) (fun v1 v2 => negb (adjacent g1 v1 v2)).
```

Standard stuff.

```
Definition injective : forall {t1 t2}, (t1 -> t2) -> Prop := fun t1 t2 f1 => forall x1 x2, f1 x1 = f1 x2 -> x1 = x2.

Definition surjective : forall {t1 t2}, (t1 -> t2) -> Prop := fun t1 t2 f1 => forall x1, exists x2, f1 x2 = x1.

Definition bijective : forall {t1 t2}, (t1 -> t2) -> Prop := fun t1 t2 f1 => injective f1 /\ surjective f1.
```

Two graphs are isomorphic if there's a bijection between their vertices that preserves adjacency.

```
Definition isomorphic : graph -> graph -> Prop := fun g1 g2 => exists f1, bijective f1 /\ (forall x1 x2, adjacent g1 x1 x2 = adjacent g2 (f1 x1) (f1 x2)).

Infix "~" := isomorphic (at level 70).
```

A helpful fact whose proof I leave to you.

```
Conjecture C1 : forall b1 b2, negb b1 = negb b2 <-> b1 = b2.
```

Your fact.

```
Goal forall g1 g2, g1 ~ g2 <-> complement g1 ~ complement g2.
Proof.
```

Access the components of the graphs.

```
destruct g1.
destruct g2.
```

Substitute defined by definition.

```
unfold isomorphic, complement, adjacent, vertices, create, projT2, projT1.
```

First-order logic simplifications.

```
firstorder.
```

Instanciation.

```
exists x1.
firstorder.
rewrite C1.
firstorder.
exists x1.
firstorder.
```

Instanciation.

```
specialize (H0 x2 x3).
rewrite C1 in H0.
firstorder.
Qed.
```

Actually, this is a formalization of graphs whose adjacency relation is decidable `V -> V -> bool`. In intuitionistic logic, not all graphs with a general adjacency relation `V -> V -> Prop` have the property you want to prove.

Instead of sticking to finite or otherwise decidable graphs, you can also move to classical logic or use double negation translation.

Comment: G.R.E.A.T.!!! Thank you! I'll read/test it carefully. I would like to have many of these examples ... they are a good way to learn. Did you use some books to learn Coq?

Comment: I did. I liked the first few chapters of [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html). Then it got a little too abstract for me. After that I just used the internet for reference and some other books like [Coq'Art](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/book/978-3-540-20854-9) and [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/).

Comment: thank you! I was going to buy Coq'Art, too ... and I already started reading the online version of [Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/). I'll give a look to Software Foundations.